# compare info from array of strings and array of jsons using lodash

Tags: arrays, json, lodash

i got array of strings

```
var users = ["user1@gmail.com","user2@gmail.com"];
```

i also got array of jsons:

```
var usersData = [
{
"email" : "user1@gmail.com",
"pass" : "1234",
"age" : 19
},
{ "email" : "user2@gmail.com",
"pass" : "123",
"age" : 20
},
{ "email" : "user3@gmail.com",
"pass" : "1234",
"age" : 25
},
{ "email" : "user4@gmail.com",
"pass" : "1234",
"age" : 28
},
{ "email" : "user5@gmail.com",
"pass" : "13go",
"age" : 35
}];
```

i want compare emails between the json and the array, json should stay -> using lodash.

Output - the Json with only the users that in the array

Comment: and what is expected output?

Comment: Output the array of Jsons with only the users in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [filter()](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) and compose a callback using [flow()](https://lodash.com/docs#flow), [partial()](https://lodash.com/docs#partial), and [partialRight()](https://lodash.com/docs#partialRight):

```
_.filter(usersData, _.flow(
  _.identity,
  _.partialRight(_.get, 'email'),
  _.partial(_.includes, users)
));
```

Which is essentially equivalent to:

```
_.filter(usersData, item => _.includes(users, item.email));
```

In this case, the one-liner is probably better, but it's handy to be able to compose callbacks too!